# Trying to count total active, inactive, and specialized memberships

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to get a count of active vs inactive memberships for classic and basic membership types -- Of the classic memberships, there are a subset of members that signed up through a different company but those memberships would also be considered classic.

So far, I have been able to select all memberships that are either classic or basic and show whether they are active or not. However, I have not had success in COUNTing how many active and inactive memberships there are for each and of the classic memberships, which were done through the different company.

So far, I have this:

```
SELECT 
    m.membershipID as MembershipID,
    m.Level,
    s.subInactive,
    CASE 
        WHEN s.subInactive = 0 THEN s.subInactive + 1
        WHEN s.subInactive = 1 THEN s.subInactive - 1
    END AS oneMeansActive
FROM dbo.membershipsStartsAndDrops m
INNER JOIN dbo.Subscriptions s on m.membershipID = s.subSubscription_ID
```

I know I'm probably on the wrong track but would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Sample Data:

```
membershipID | Level | subInactive | OneMeansActive
1             Classic      0              1
2             Basic        0              1
3             Classic      0              0
```

Desired Result:

```
ActClassic | ActBasic | InaClassic | InaBasic | ActSpecial
  83079        5607       12658        3403        1270
```

Columns = Active classic memberships, active basic memberships, inactive classic memberships, inactive basic memberships, active classic memberships that signed up through 3rd party company.

I can't figure out how to count all of these values and also group them like this. I'm pulling data from 2 different databases as well. The classic memberships that signed up through the 3rd party company come from same DB as tbl_subscription. The table it comes from is company_members

Comment: I edited my post above to include sample data and the desired results

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want conditional aggregation.  Something like this:

```
select sum(case when level = 'Classic' then OneMeansActive else 0 end) as numClassicActives,
       sum(case when level = 'Basic' then OneMeansActive else 0 end) as numBasicActives,
       sum(case when level = 'Classic' then subInactive else 0 end) as numClassicSubinactives,
       sum(case when level = 'Classic' then subInactive else 0 end) as numBasicSubinactives  
from company_members m
```